# RTMP Protocol Streaming Cannot Connect

Tags: 10.10, video, flash, internet

Greetings,

I am working on a clean install of Ubuntu 10.10 Maverick. I am trying to use vivu.tv's webinar features, but I am consistently getting a connection error. This occurs on both Lucid and Maverick, using both Chrome and Firefox. We were able to test with the support team for vivu.tv, and we confirmed that it worked fine with http tunneling, but broke when they switched to rtmp. (Them using http tunneling is not an option, so I got to get my system to work with rtmp.)

You should be able to replicate this problem by going to this link:

http://vivu.tv/vivuweb/home/featuredarchives/

A box will begin a Startup Check, will stall on Connecting to Media Servers, and then will display an error stating that it was unable to connect to the media server.

This is a time sensitive issue for me, as I require access to several archived webinars for an important course I am developing.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using 10.10 on AMD64 platform and the video is working fine **without** having installed ubuntu-restricted-extras.

I've reopened the page a few times and i've experienced the problem you're facing.

"Configuring playback" seems to stuck there sometimes, but as soon as the timebar is loaded (total time 1:52:07), if i scroll to the right a few seconds or minutes, the video starts playing correctly.